# Checking if a video has a sound even if it has an audio codec?

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg

I am new to intermediate python and I am trying to find if a downloaded video has sound, every video I download has an audio codec but I want to get the decibel of sound that audio has in that particular video.

For example, this 'FFmpeg' command line script allows me to get the full info:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i testvideo.mp4 -af volumedetect -vn -f null - 2>&1
```

this yields the below result in my command prompt(windows user here with win 11)

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'testvideo.mp4':

Metadata:

major_brand : mp42

minor_version : 0

compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomavc1

creation_time : 2022-04-12T23:21:45.000000Z

Duration: 00:00:40.58, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4104 kb/s

Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 3846 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn (default)

Metadata:

creation_time : 2022-04-12T23:21:45.000000Z

handler_name : L-SMASH Video Handler

vendor_id : [0][0][0][0]

encoder : AVC Coding

Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 253 kb/s (default)

Metadata:

creation_time : 2022-04-12T23:21:45.000000Z

handler_name : L-SMASH Audio Handler

vendor_id : [0][0][0][0]

Stream mapping:

Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (aac (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))

Press [q] to stop, [?] for help

Output #0, null, to 'pipe:':

Metadata:

major_brand : mp42

minor_version : 0

compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomavc1

encoder : Lavf59.35.100

Stream #0:0(und): Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)

Metadata:

creation_time : 2022-04-12T23:21:45.000000Z

handler_name : L-SMASH Audio Handler

vendor_id : [0][0][0][0]

encoder : Lavc59.56.100 pcm_s16le

size=N/A time=00:00:40.55 bitrate=N/A speed=1.22e+03x

video:0kB audio:7608kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown

[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0000026609be08c0] n_samples: 3895296

[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0000026609be08c0] mean_volume: -91.0 dB

[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0000026609be08c0] max_volume: -91.0 dB

[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0000026609be08c0] histogram_91db: 3895296
```

As you can see there are 'parsed_volumedetect' values with dB which has a mean value of -91 dB which means the audio has no sound, i.e., the video has audio but there is no sound.

Now I am trying to do the same in python and I want to get just the mean volume value to be stored in a variable so that I can check if the video has any sound in it.

I have seen the subprocess codes so far but when I try to run my code in VS-Code - python 3.11:

```
import subprocess    
result = subprocess.run(["ffmpeg", "-hide_banner", "-af", "volumedetect", "-vn", "-f", "null", "testvideo1.mp4"],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    shell=True)
    print(result.stdout)
```

It says that:

```
PS C:\Users\balaj\OneDrive\Documents\Programming language\python files> c:; cd 'c:\Users\balaj\OneDrive\Documents\Programming language\python files'; & 'C:\Python311\python.exe' 'c:\Users\balaj\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.20.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '51760' '--' 'c:\Users\balaj\OneDrive\Documents\Programming language\python files\devproject\sample.py'

b"Output #0, null, to 'testvideo1.mp4':\r\nOutput file #0 does not contain any stream\r\n"
```

Any help is much appreciated. Sorry for the long post... TIA!!!

Just a quick update:
The result is the same for video files that have sound(I tested in VLC) and don't have sound.

Another update:
I have changed the `subprocess.run`code to the exact same as I called in the cmd windows:

```
result = subprocess.run(["ffmpeg", "-hide_banner","-i","testvideo-sound.mp4", "-af", "volumedetect", "-vn", "-f", "null", "-2>&1"]
```

Now the result is this :

```
b'The handle could not be duplicated\r\nduring redirection of handle 1.\r\n'
```

Comment: If you use this ffmpeg command, on stdout you get nothing, just skip it. The info (and if there is any error, the errormessage) comes on stderr, but in chunks, and it needs decoding. Ive suggest to you, focus on stderr stream event 'data' chunks, if the "max_volume" is in the decoded chunk, you got it, and if the stream event 'close' and didnt find it yet, handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me. I tried it with a few different video files (mp4) I had lying around.

```py
import subprocess
import re

files = [
    # list of file paths
]

def find_volume(s):
    # regex to find volume in a string
    m = re.search("(?:max_volume: )(?P<volume>.+ dB)", s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    
    if not m:
        return None

    return m.groupdict()["volume"]

    

for filepath in files:
    r = subprocess.run(f'ffmpeg -i "{filepath}" -filter:a volumedetect -f null /dev/null',
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
            shell=True
    )
    # "volume" will be either None or a string;
    # if it is none, we go to do to the "else" body
    # instead, because None if 'falsy'.
    if volume := find_volume(r.stdout.decode("utf-8")):
        print(f'Video file "{filepath}" has a max volume of {volume}')
    else:
        print(f'Video file "{filepath}" has no audio')
```